# How to check if a file descriptor/ memory is mmap able?

Tags: python

I am trying to access a memory location "/dev/xdma_h2c_0". I have achieved the read/write using system read/write functions.
Now I am trying to use mmap to do the same. But I am getting No such device error.
Is there a quick way to tell whether a location/file descriptor is mmap (-able) or not?
(This memory location is available on the Xilinx Virtex FPGA board using the Xilinx drivers)

Comment: This is a region of memory exposed by the FPGA? Is `/dev/xdma_h2c_0` a character device or block device? What is the errno? `ENODEV` / `ENOENT`? From what you've provided, I'd suggest it isn't, but that doesn't mean you can't potentially improve the driver to make it possible!

Comment: Yes. It's a character device. Errno as given by python script is "OSError: [Errno 19] No such device". Can you tell from this whether is possible to mmap it?

Comment: You cannot `mmap()` character devices - they aren't seekable, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, `/dev/xdma_h2c_0` is a character device, and thus it is not possible to use `mmap()` on it - that just makes no sense, primarily because it's not an addressable device (you can't use `lseek()` / `fseek()` either).

If the FPGA's address space is presented via PCI / PCIe, then you might have luck with using `lspci` to locate its memory regions, opening `/dev/mem`, and using `mmap()` with that... though this comes with all relevant security concerns and warnings... i.e: don't do this in a real product or outside the lab / home.

More ideally though, you'd write a proper drive to expose whatever functionality you're providing in the FPGA.

---

According to your follow-up comments, you *are* able to call `lseek()` on the device, which is not typical for character devices.

The [`file_operations` structure](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/fs.h?h=v5.0-rc6#n1783) outlines what "*features*" are available from the device or node.

> Is that because the address space is presented via the Xilinx PCIe drivers?

Looking in the mainline kernel I can't immediately see the driver, but if the interface to the FPGA is indeed PCIe, and there isn't some weird windowing mechanism used, then I would imagine there is some flag region of memory available and therefore a method for seeking within it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just a small doubt.
I can actually lseek() it since that's how I implemented read/write using system functions (os.lseek() then os.read()/os.write() in python). Is that because the address space is presented via the Xilinx PCIe drivers?

Comment: Interesting - it's not typically possible to use `lseek()` on a character device... See my update :-)